# how to run poll with a timeout in networking Ts

Tags: c++, networking, boost-asio

I have a ip::tcp::acceptor socket, I want to poll and check if it is ready for accept, rather than block and call accept, but I would like to do this with a timeout.

```
net::io_context ioc;
auto endpoint = ip::basic_endpoint<ip::tcp> 
 (ip::address_v4::loopback(), port_num);
auto socket = ip::tcp::acceptor(ioc, ip::tcp::v4());
std::error_code ec;
socket.bind(endpoint);
socket.listen();
auto ct = ioc.poll_one();
auto tcp_socket = socket.accept();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start the call to poll_one is not doing anything..  there is no async work waiting to it's going to return immediately.

The above code will "block" on the "accept" call until you get a new socket accepted.

There is no way (what I know of) to do a timeout in this situation.  You have to use the async methods at this point if you want a timeout control.

e.g. (using boost asio)

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

int main()
{
    const unsigned short port_num = 100;
    boost::asio::io_context ioc;
    auto endpoint = boost::asio::ip::basic_endpoint<boost::asio::ip::tcp>(boost::asio::ip::address_v4::loopback(), port_num);
    auto acceptor = boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor(ioc, boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4());
    auto timer = boost::asio::system_timer(ioc);

    acceptor.bind(endpoint);
    acceptor.listen();

    timer.expires_from_now(10s);
    timer.async_wait([&acceptor](auto const& ec)
        {
            if (!ec)
            {
                std::cout << "timed out";
                boost::system::error_code cec;
                acceptor.cancel(cec);
            }
        });

    acceptor.async_accept([&timer](auto const& ec, auto tcp_socket)
        {
            if(!ec)
            {
                std::cout << "socket accepted";
                boost::system::error_code cec;
                timer.cancel(cec);
                tcp_socket.shutdown(boost::asio::socket_base::shutdown_both);
            }
        });

    ioc.run();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```